# Run .exe on C++ from C# with arguments

Tags: c#, c++

I have one application on C++ and one on C# (for GUI).

I run exe - file (C++) from C# in new process and pass parameters to the command line.

Code C#:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process Proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
Proc.StartInfo.FileName = "main.exe";
Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "p";
Proc.Start();
```

Code C++:

```
if (char(argv[1]) == 'p') 
     {
            program.SetUniform("cur_color", make_float3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f));
            std::cout << "This is true" << std::endl;
     }
else {
            std::cout << "This is false    " << argv[1] << std::endl;
            program.SetUniform("cur_color", make_float3(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f));
     }
```

But I got "This is false   p" as a result.

I don't know why. Can you help me? Could there be a problem with the type of argument being passed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do comparing this way, because arguments in C++ are delivered as `char**` where `argv[0] argv[1]` etc. are arrays created from arguments separated by space.

Example:

```
main.exe foo bar

argv[0] == ['f','o','o']
argv[1] == ['b','a','r']
```

Documentation: [HERE](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DEN36Up4/)

So you need to iterate through the characters for comparison or make `std::vector<std:string>` from **argv**

Example:

```
C# Program Calling C++ Exe
  main.exe p foo bar
C++ Program Getting Parameters and comparing them
  argv[1][0] == 'p'
```

Simpler way to compare, but not faster in non complex solutions:

```
std::vector<std::string> vectorOfArguments(argv + 1, argv + argc);
```

Then you can just browse through vector

```
for(auto & argument : vectorOfArguments){
   //Some Action
}
```

Hope it helped